# DropDownList Value in BulkEditGridView Not Saving

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, visual-studio-2015

Newbie here.

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Community.  Working on a C# Web Forms application for an NFL Pickem game.  I have a Game Edit screen which lists NFL games from a Games table and I want to allow editing the Winning Team field from a drop down list.  The drop down list is bound to a Teams table which is a foreign key in the Games table.  I am using the BulkEditGridView control from  Matt Dotson's RealWorldGrids with SQL Data Sources.

When I run the page it displays all games properly.  It also binds the DropDownList to the Teams properly.  However, when I change the Winning Team from the DropDownList and click Save it does not save the change.  There are no errors, it just refreshes and shows the original value back in the DropDownList.

Code:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="GameEdit.aspx.cs" Inherits="Pickem.Admin.GameEdit" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<rwg:BulkEditGridView ID="GameEditBulkEditGrid" DataSourceID="GameEditDataSource" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    DataKeyNames="ID,Winning Team" SaveButtonID="SaveButton" runat="server" Width="600px" EnableInsert="False" InsertRowCount="1">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ID" DataField="ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Week" DataField="Week" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Week" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="DateTime" DataField="DateTime" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="DateTime" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Home Team" DataField="Home Team" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="HomeTeamID" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Visiting Team" DataField="Visiting Team" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Visiting Team" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Winning Team">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="TeamsDropDownList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="TeamsDataSource" DataTextField="CityShort" DataValueField="ID" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("[ID]") %>'>
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="TeamsDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:PickemDb %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Teams]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</rwg:BulkEditGridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="GameEditDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:PickemDb %>"
    SelectCommand="
    SELECT Games.ID, Games.Week, Games.DateTime, h.CityShort as 'Home Team', v.CityShort as 'Visiting Team', w.CityShort as 'Winning Team'
    FROM [Games]
    LEFT JOIN Teams h on Games.HomeTeamID = h.ID
    LEFT JOIN Teams v on Games.VisitingTeamID = v.ID
    LEFT JOIN Teams w on Games.WinningTeamID = w.ID
    "
    UpdateCommand="
    UPDATE [Games]
    SET [WinningTeamID] = @WinningTeamID
    FROM [Games]
    WHERE [ID] = @ID
    ">
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Type="int32" Name="Winning Team"></asp:Parameter>
        <asp:Parameter Type="int32" Name="ID"></asp:Parameter>
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:Button ID="SaveButton" runat="server" Text="Save" />
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: it seem that your page is refresh before saving data

Comment: the better solution is that you assign the datasource from server side